# Java Mobile Application

Tags: java, android

Can any one tell me the book which can help me developing the application for Android ( java based), Please tell me about the IDE as well so that I can read and try myself.

Comment: Come on Ashish, no spoon feeding here. Just Download the dev kit which includes the eclipse IDE and follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of IDE, you can use Eclipse, and install the Android SDK over it. Basically, use the ADT Eclipse plugin for Android - http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

And in terms of a book, there is enough documentation on the Android dev website - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/index.html